# Iterate through the resultset bs4

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have used bs4 to extract this resultset in bs4.

```
<div> 
<div>
</div>
Content 1
</div>

<div>
Content 2
</div>
```

I am trying to extract these 2 elements.

`Moi not cute not hot, the ugly bui bui type 1` and  `Actually, moi also dun know`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
r = urllib.urlopen(
    'http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/%5Bofficial%5D-chit-chat-students-part-2-a-5526993-55.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
letters = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id":re.compile("post_message_\d+")})
```

Here is my code. However, how do i iterate through the result set so that it only extracts the content way before the closing div.

`letters.find_all('div')` returns an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

All the messages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

r = urllib.urlopen(
    'http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/%5Bofficial%5D-chit-chat-students-part-2-a-5526993-55.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
letters = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id":re.compile("post_message_\d+")})
for a in letters:
    print [b.strip() for b in a.text.strip().split('\n') if b.strip()]
```

Comment: `print [b.strip() for b in a.text.strip().split('\n') if b.strip()]`. You can omit .strip() in b.strip().